# Inline form is not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a inline bootstrap 4 form occupying the full width (without spaces between the inputs and the button) with:

- 1 input type text and 1 button In extra small devices
- 2 input type text and 1 buttons In small devices
- 3 input type text and 1 buttons In medium and larger devices

But it is not working with the code below. I dont know if it is because the place where the form opens and close. Here is the example:
https://jsfiddle.net/o8jzq00f/1/

Html:

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-success">

  <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-center" style="background-color: orange">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1 class="m-3">Title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-center">
    <form>
      <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="Jane Doe">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3  hidden-xs-up">
        <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="Jon Doe">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 hidden-md-up">
        <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="Jon Doe">
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: i fixed your grid:

https://jsfiddle.net/syedz/o8jzq00f/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row` class to bind your column then it will work
`<div class="row">...under this you can use col classes and specify the width ...</div>`

Comment: Try using row class after the ``` form ``` tag and inside row you can use your grid method but first specify row and under that do all your stuffs